# JQuery ready function problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events, dropshadow

I am using the dropShadow plugin, and I have a problem with the JQuery `ready` function.

When I have my code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#shadow').dropShadow();
    $('#navigation li.mainmenu').bind('mouseover', navigation_open);
    $('#navigation li').bind('mouseout', navigation_timer);
});
```

It will only make the shadow once the drop menu has come out, which is the second function.  Any ideas why?

The full code for the JS is:

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{
   $('#navigation li.mainmenu').bind('mouseover', navigation_open);
   $('#navigation li').bind('mouseout',  navigation_timer);
  });
 var timeout    = 500;
 var closetimer = 0;
 var ddmenuitem = 0;
 var highlightmenu = 0;
 var returncolor = 0;
 var textreturncolor = 0;
 var height = 0;
 var originaltop = 0;
 var resettop = 0;
 var top = 0;
 var shadowExists = 0;
 var dropshadow = 0;
function drawShadow(){
 //draw the shadow only on mouse enter
 dropshadow = $(this).find('ul').dropShadow({top: 4, opacity: 1});
 $('.dropShadow').css('visibility','visible');
 }
 function navigation_open()
 {  navigation_canceltimer();
    navigation_close();
     height = $(this).height();
ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul');
//Double Liners are above 40 pixels
menu = ddmenuitem.find('li');
/*===Need to get the top pos. of the item and adjust it since it is absolute;      relative does not work*/
top = ddmenuitem.position().top;
resettop = top;
   if (height > 40){
    top = top - 53;
    }
    else{
    top = top - 35;
    }
ddmenuitem.css('top', top.toString() + "px");
//---ADD A DROP SHADOW...USING JQUERY PLUGIN
ddmenuitem.dropShadow({top: 4, opacity: 1});
$('.dropShadow').css('visibility','visible');
ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'visible');
returncolor = $(this).find('a#highlight').css('background-color');
textreturncolor = $(this).find('a#highlight').css('color');
highlightmenu = $(this).find('a#highlight').css('background-color','#6487ad');
highlightmenu.css('color','#ffffff');
highlightmenu.css('font-weight','bold');}

 function navigation_close()
 {  if(ddmenuitem){
ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
ddmenuitem.css('top',resettop);
ddmenuitem.removeShadow();
}
if(highlightmenu){ highlightmenu.css('background-color',returncolor);
                    highlightmenu.css('color',textreturncolor);
                    }
 }

 function navigation_timer()
 {
  closetimer = window.setTimeout(navigation_close, timeout);}

 function navigation_canceltimer()
 {  if(closetimer)
    {
    window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
       closetimer = null;}}

 document.onclick = navigation_close;
```

The HTML would be like this for static:

```
<div id="shadow">
//images here
</div>
```

I don't know if you need to see anymore, however the drop menu is just a list, but I want to be able to apply this to the static images and it won't until the drop menus come out.

Comment: Can you provide a little HTML snippet to help give context?

Comment: maybe you can provide some demo code?

Comment: I've updated it on my question thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within the CSS, when calling dropShadow() for the first time the css for class dropShadow is set to hiddent (this was placed there to make the dynamic pieces work in IE (all other browsers fine without it).  In the javascript you can see this by the  $('.dropShadow').css('visibility','visible'); being called.

Answer (score 1):

The dropshadow plugin appears to be designed for stationary page elements.  From the dropshadow js file:

"This jQuery plug-in adds soft drop shadows behind page elements. It is only intended for adding a few drop shadows to mostly stationary objects, like a page heading, a photo, or content containers"

EDIT: Perhaps you could achieve the effect you're looking for with css? http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/

Comment: It works well with the drop menus, just not the static images.  it loads the images' shadow when a drop menu comes out even though it has nothing to do with the dropmenu.  I am not sure why.  Thanks for your help, I've tried the CSS route and CSS 3 isn't largely supported right now especially that effect, I may use gimp to add it to add the effect to the images I want.  I just thought if it was possible to do it via Jquery it will make updating the site easier.

Comment: Ah ok.  The link above covers IE 5.5 as well as recent (though not bleeding edge) versions of populer browsers, so it's not purely css3. But if you really want to go the jquery route, you may want to provide a simple fiddle to show the issue (http://jsfiddle.net) and we may be able to help more.